# How to "Lock down" V8?

Tags: javascript, python, sandbox, embedded-v8

I'm new to V8 and plan on using it in a python web application. The purpose is to let users submit and execute certain JS scripts. Obviously this is a security threat so I'm looking for resources that document the ways one might 'lock down' v8. For example, can I create a white list of functions allowed to be called? Or a blacklist of libraries not allowed to be referenced?

Comment: BTW why not allow them to submit Python scripts? This would simplify your architecture a bit I think. :-) (Had to mention it). And yes, it's possible to create a safe Python sandbox for those scripts

Comment: @Kos how? I'm interested as well, but I keep reading everywhere that Python is nearly unsandboxable, with a thousand examples of how to break out

Answer (score 1):

If you use a plain V8 (i.e. not something like node.js) there won't be any dangerous functions. JavaScript itself doesn't have a stdlib containing filesystem functions etc.

The only thing a malicious user can do is creating infinite loops, deep recursions and memory hogs.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but I'm interested in this too. How can you prevent the user from exceeding a memory/processing quota?

Comment: No idea. Please [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this.

Comment: I just posted a new question regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637075/how-do-i-prevent-malicious-javascript-in-v8-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Would simply locking down the V8 instance (ie: giving it no permissions in a chroot) and killing the process if it doesn't return after a certain amount of time not work?