# How do I prevent malicious javascript in V8 (with Python)

Tags: javascript, python, v8

I'm using PyV8 to run untrusted javascript. How can I detect and kill javascript that has inifinite, or long running loops in it? I'd like to tell v8 to run javascript and fail with a timeout if it's not finished in 0.1 of a second.

Comment: Step 1: Solve the halting problem

Comment: Step 2: Prove NP = P (or simply use a timeout instead of trying to determine it before running the code)

Answer (score 3):

if it's python, you can use Interrupting cow:

```
from interruptingcow import timeout

try:
    with timeout(5, exception=RuntimeError):
        # perform a potentially very slow operation
        pass
except RuntimeError:
    print "didn't finish within 5 seconds"
```

https://bitbucket.org/evzijst/interruptingcow

Comment: does this work on windows? -- The docs mention SIGALRM which I wouldn't think to be available on windows.